# Kinnah about mazalos out of order

Tags: tefilla, tisha-bav

One of the *Kinnos* that is said the night of *Tisha B'Av* discusses the different *mazalos*/constellations. In the Artscroll version it's listed as *Kinnah* #5. Artscroll has a nice chart at the bottom explaining the correlation between *mazalos* and the months of the year. I'm not sure their source, other than it seems to line up with commonly known horoscopes.

1. טלה / Ram or Lamb / Aries - **Nissan**
2. שור / Bull / Taurus - **Iyar**
3. תאומים / Twins / Gemini - **Sivan**
4. סרטן / Crab / Cancer - **Tammuz**
5. אריה / Lion / Leo - **Av**
6. בתולה / Maiden / Virgo - **Elul**
7. מאזנים / Scales / Libra - **Tishrei**
8. עקרב / Scorpion / Scorpio - **Marchehvan**
9. קשת / Rainbow / Sagittarius - **Kislev**
10. גדי / Goat or Kid / Capricorn - **Teves**
11. דלי / Bucket / Aquarius - **Shevat**
12. דגים / Fish / Pisces - **Adar**

In reading the *Kinnah*, I noticed that all the *mazalos* are in chrological order, except #10 and #11.

1. טלה
2. שור
3. תאומים
4. סרטן
5. אריה
6. בתולה
7. מאזנים
8. עקרב
9. קשת
10. **דלי**
11. **גדי**
12. דגים

Are there any explanations provided for why the switch?

Comment: For Artscroll's source, you can see [Rashi RH 11b](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=9&daf=11b&format=pdf) (9 lines from the bottom)